# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', only errors on first call but works subsequently

Tags: facebook, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have an AngularJS app which is trying to auth with my Web Api. I receive the below error during the first call to my server if the user does not exist in my database, but does not happen on subsequent calls to the same method once the user exists in my db. (relevant code at the bottom)

*No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:1378' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.*

The flow of the logic is:

1. AngularJS auths with Facebook when the user clicks login
2. App does an $http.post to my server for auth/login passing their credentials
3. Server polls Facebook API for user details
4. If user exists, update their profile and auth 'em
5. Else, create new membership user, update with FB details, and auth 'em

The only thing that's different if they don't exist in the database (which is when the defect occurs) is that the login method asynchronously calls a createUser method then returns data. No additional external calls are made.

API startup method enabling CORS:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
    var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*","*","*");
    config.EnableCors(cors);

    ConfigureOAuth(app);

    app_start.WebApiConfig.Register(config);
    app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

    app.UseWebApi(config);
}
```

API Controller:

```
[Route("Login")]
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<FacebookUserModel> Login(FacebookUserRequest user)
{
    FacebookUserModel fbUser = new FacebookUserModel();

    // Build FacebookUser object
    try  {
        // Grab basic user details
        string profileRequestUri = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + user.fbID + "?access_token=" + user.access_token;
        HttpWebRequest profileRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(profileRequestUri);
        profileRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
        profileRequest.Accept = "application/json";
        HttpWebResponse profileResponse = (HttpWebResponse)profileRequest.GetResponse();
        Stream profileResponseStream = profileResponse.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader profileStreamReader = new StreamReader(profileResponseStream);
        fbUser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FacebookUserModel>(profileStreamReader.ReadToEnd());
    } catch (Exception) ...

    try {
        // Grab profile picture
        string pictureRequestUri = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + user.fbID + "/picture";
        HttpWebRequest pictureRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(pictureRequestUri);
        pictureRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
        HttpWebResponse pictureResponse = (HttpWebResponse)pictureRequest.GetResponse();
        fbUser.profilePictureUri = pictureResponse.ResponseUri.ToString();
    } catch (Exception) ...

    // If user exists, change password to new token and return)
    if(userExists)
    {
        try {
            IdentityUser identityUser = _repo.FindUser(ID, pass).Result;
            FacebookUserModel dbUser = db.FacebookUserObjects.First(u => u.identityUserID == identityUser.Id);

            db.Entry(dbUser).CurrentValues.SetValues(fbUser);
            db.SaveChangesAsync();

            fbUser.identityUserID = identityUser.Id;
            return fbUser;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { return null; }
    }
    // Else, create the new user using same scheme
    else
    {
        UserModel newUser = new UserModel
        {
            UserName = ID,
            Password = pass,
            ConfirmPassword = pass
        };

        // Create user in Identity & linked Facebook record
        createUser(newUser, fbUser);

        return fbUser;
    }
}

private async void createUser(UserModel newUser, FacebookUserModel fbUser)
{
    IdentityResult result = await _repo.RegisterUser(newUser);
    var identityUser = await _repo.FindUser(newUser.UserName, newUser.Password);
    fbUser.identityUserID = identityUser.Id;

    db.FacebookUserObjects.Add(fbUser);
    db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

AngularJS calls to my server:

```
var _login = function (fbID, fbToken) {
    $http.post(serviceBase + 'auth/login', { "fbID": fbID, "access_token": fbToken }).then(function (response) {

        var data = "grant_type=password&username=" + fbID + "&password=" + pass;

        $http.post(serviceBase + 'auth/token', data, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } })
            .success(function (tokenResponse) {

                authServiceFactory.bearerToken = tokenResponse.access_token;
            })
            .error(function (err) {
                console.log("token error:", err);
            });

        authServiceFactory.userObject = response.data;
        window.localStorage['userObject'] = JSON.stringify(authServiceFactory.userObject);
    })
};
```

Why would I get the No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error only on the first call, but not subsequent ones?

**Update**

I have a workaround in place that works, but I don't really like. The issue only arose when calling a second method from my login controller, so if I moved that code up into the login controller instead of a secondary method it works without the CORS error. This really bothers me though and is inefficient, I'd love to know a better way around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're working with angularjs you might want to check out [satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer). It makes the auth process really simple and has some awesome built in window popup control.

As far as the Access-Control-Allow-Origin calls it could be happening because you explicitly set headers on the one call and the other ones are falling back to the default http provider?  Check out [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) and see if providing those defaults might work around it.